# Why prior and latter element in array get mixed up when pointing to a local struct outside of scope?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, scope

So I'm testing some functionality of accessing a struct by declaring a variable typed struct compare to using malloc. And I know that when creating a struct variable through declaring, it will only exist inside that scope and will get destroyed after that scope ends. I have a program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Edge {
    int edgeNum;
    struct Edge* next;
}Edge;

typedef struct Vertex {
    int vertexNum;
    Edge* next;
}Vertex;

void addEdge(Vertex* v, int edgeNum) {
    Edge* currentEdge;
    Edge newEdge;
    
  
        newEdge.edgeNum = edgeNum;
        if (v->next == NULL) {
            v->next = &newEdge;
    
        } else {
            currentEdge = v->next;
            while (currentEdge->next != NULL) currentEdge = currentEdge->next;
            
            currentEdge->next = &newEdge;  //this part doesnt represent a real graph
        }
        newEdge.next = NULL;
}
    
    


int main()
{
    int IG[7][14] = { {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} };
    
    int i, j;
    
    Vertex v[7];
    Edge *new_edge;
    Edge *current;
    
    for(i=0; i < 7; i++){
        
        /* Set order number to each list */
        v[i].vertexNum = i+1;
        /* Initialize the edge list with NULL */
        v[i].next = NULL;
        
        for(j=0; j < 14; j++){
            if( IG[i][j] == 1 ){
                addEdge(&v[i],j+1);
                if (i>0)
                printf(" line %d: %d and line%d: %d\n",i-1,v[i-1].next->edgeNum, i, v[i].next->edgeNum);
            }
            
        }
        
                    
    }
       

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm looping through each line of matrix, if it encounter 1 then we will create a struct Edge to it. I know it doesn't work because the struct is out of its scope, however the result was not as I expected. Because I expected that at the end, each element inside v[] array should be pointing to NULL because the struct was destroyed.

However not only it's not pointing to NULL, the latter element seems to passing its struct to the element prior to it. This is my first time experience this behavior so I couldn't find words to describe as well.

After the loop is finished, if we go through the element inside the array once again, all the elements pointing to the struct of the last element inside array.

For example: in line 2 of the matrix, the only 1 is the entry2x1, so even if the struct exist, it should be 1, but it becomes 13 because of the last line of matrix, the last 1 appears at position 13. Same goes for other line as well, all becomes 13.

If anyone could explain to me what's wrong in my predition, it would be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing is "destroyed" in C when it goes out of scope. Whatever was declared is simply abandoned in place, either on the stack or in a register. Wherever it is, it will very likely be overwritten with other stuff in subsequent operations and calls. It might stick around on the stack unchanged until there are other function calls or other allocations from the stack, but this is not assured by C. Accessing the out-of-scope variable is undefined behavior.

In this case, every instance of `newEdge` is created in the same location on the stack by each `addEdge()` call, with the previous contents overwritten on each call, as well as overwritten by other calls, such as the `printf()`.

Comment: Wow, that is really helpful and clears up a lot. I will make sure to look into this based on your answer. Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding.